# On MobaXTerm, what bash command can I use to open a file from a remote machine? instead of clicking on 'Open with default text editor'

Tags: linux, ssh

What I'm trying to accomplish is *not* to right click on the SFTP tab on 'Open with default text editor', but to do this from the command line.

Comment: Do you have a X server running on your local machine?

Comment: Yes. I do have an x server running on windows

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with running remote X clients then passing the filename to `xdg-open` will open it in its default (X client) application provided your SSH client has X forwarding enabled.

```
xdg-open foo.txt
```

If you're trying to open the remote file in a local application, that's not something that can be done from the remote command line.

Comment: That's the way I currently do but there is a considerable lag in the process. There has to be a way to invoke the command that Mobaxterm uses from the sftp tab. It downloads the file and you edit it locally.

Comment: What would be the impediment?

Comment: The complete and utter lack of any protocol for doing so. It is theoretically possible to use X to send a message to an application listening locally that tells MobaXTerm to download and open the file, but I am not aware of any existing tool for doing this.